# How to plot the orientation of a rigid body on 2D plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, differential-equations, rigid-bodies

I am working on numerically integrating (with Euler method currently, but I plan to upgrade to Runge-Kutta in the future) a fourth order 3-dimensional system of differential equations in Python. The system has two spatial variables (x and y) and 1 rotational coordinate (theta), to display the orientation of the rigid body the system describes.

I was able to integrate the system just fine, and used matplotlib to generate plots of the x-coordinate versus the y-coordinate. This is a sample of the plot generated:
[image]

However, I would like to have a plot more like this:

[image]

Taken from Formation tracking control for multiple rigid bodies on matrix Lie
groups: A system decomposition approach by J. Sun and Z. Geng.

Here, they acheived a 2D plot of x vs. y, but also managed to show the orientation of the object at each instance along the trajectory. Does anyone know I could accomplish this with matplotlib?

Comment: Python turtle can handle most of that. :)